# Opencart - link do produto

Tags: opencart

Boa tarde estou utilizando o opencart Versão 3.0.2.1. E no banner de produtos no campo index preciso referenciar o id do produto para adicionar o produto ao carrinho. Onde encontro o link do produto?

Obrigado

Comment: Tem acesso direto ao banco de dados? Se tiver, não seria o ``oc_product.product_id`` ?

Comment: Ola Cleber tenho sim, e ´tem esse arquivo oc_produto.product_id mas preciso da rota até ele como posso obtêla

Comment: Você pode fazer a busca na própria página do Opencart e copiar o link do resultado.
Também tem o modulo de exportar e importar que gera planilhas em excel que ajuda bastante na edição em massa dos produtos e nela você pode ver o id dos produtos segue o link para o modulo caso interesse:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17&filter_search=Export/Import%20Tool&filter_license=0